# How avoid getter/setter functions in the module pattern when passing arguments

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, module-pattern

For some time now, I've been structuring my JavaScript Code like this:

```
;(function() {
    function Example(name, purpose) {
        this.name = name;
        this. purpose = purpose;
    }

    Example.prototype.getInfo = function() {
        return 'The purpose of "' + this.name + '" is: ' + this.purpose;
    }

    Example.prototype.showInfo = function() {
        alert(this.getInfo());
    }

    var ex = new Example('someModule', 'Showing some stuff.');

    ex.showInfo();
})(undefined);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q76h0ps/)

Now I've realized that this pattern is far from ideal as is has some problems:

- It doesn't utilize closures/scope so simulate public & private
  members.
- It doesn't export something, meaning the module itself is not really encapsulated & namespaced.

(Disclaimer: I haven't used it in any bigger project, so I might be missing some important details that occur when working under real live conditions.)

To solve these issues, I started looking into JavaScript design patterns. One of patterns that immediately appealed to me is the *module pattern*.
I tried to rewrite the code above using the module pattern, but I can't get it quite right:

```
var Example = (function() {

    function getInfo() {
        return 'The purpose of "' + name + '" is: ';
    }

    // Public stuff
    return {
        name: '',
        purpose: '',
        setInfo: function(name, purpose) {
            this.name = name;
            this.purpose = purpose;
        },
        showInfo: function() {
            alert(getInfo());
        }
    };
})(undefined);

Example.setInfo('someModule', 'Showing some stuff.');
Example.showInfo();
```

Non working Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly66mcxo/)

Now the module itself is encapsulated inside the `Example` namespace & there is something like public & private members, but working with it is quite different & difficult to me, probably because I can't wrap my head around the fact that there is no instance created using the `new` keyword.

In the non working example, why does it alert `result` although that string is never set & why is `purpose` not alerted? I think the `setInfo` method itself works, so it's probably a scope issue I don't understand.

Also, is there a way around using getter/setter functions? To me it currently looks like assignments I would normally do in the constructor aren't really possible using the module pattern:

```
function Example(name, purpose) {
    this.name = name;
    this. purpose = purpose;
}
```

Using the module pattern, I either have to user getter/setter *or* something like a 'universal setter function' in form of an init function.

Coming from PHP OOP, I always try to avoid them as much as possible, but I don't really know how to handle that in a prototype based language.

Maybe there is something similar to the module pattern, but with using prototypes – something like module & constructor pattern? It might be easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way and it should work and you are right, this is scope issue.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx4hsceh/1/)

Notice that I have taken snapshot of `this` in a variable and am using that. It is usually done in order to keep a reference to `this` when the context is changing.

**No use of new Keyword**
In your case returning {} is returning a new instance of anonymous object with properties as defined. Hence, you do not need new keyword also. You can take a look at [this](http://3dmdesign.com/development/javascript-variables-and-anonymous-objects) for anonymous objects.

When you use `this`, the scope of `this` changes in return {} object and they no more refer to the Example object.

**Using getter / setter function**
You don't need them. assignments would do, but remember, the variables would be attached with self so you would need to do `self.name = name` and `self.purpose = purpose` in order to do assignments or get values.

```
var Example = (function() {
    var self = this;
    function getInfo() {
        return 'The purpose of "' + name + '" is: ' + purpose;
    }

    // Public stuff
    return {
        name: '',
        purpose: '',
        setInfo: function(name, purpose) {
            self.name = name;
            self.purpose = purpose;
        },
        showInfo: function() {
            alert(getInfo());
        }
    };
})(undefined);

Example.setInfo('someModule', 'Showing some stuff.');
Example.showInfo();
```

**Update:**
Fiddle wasn't saved properly I have updated that. Also In there I just corrected your code.

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/14qa01az/4/) is what you are trying to achieve:

```
var Example = (function (params) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = params.name;
    self.purpose = params.purpose;

    function getInfo() {       
        return 'The purpose of "' + self.name + '" is: ' + self.purpose;
    };
    self.showInfo(alert(getInfo()));

    return{

    };
});

var myExample = new Example({
    name: 'someModule',
    purpose: 'somePurpose'
});
myExample.showInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The code you posted works, but somewhere in the fiddle is an error. Anyway: When I don't need getters & setters, then why there is also a `setInfo` method in your code – isn't this a setter?

Comment: My fiddle wasnt linked properly ... I have updated that. Also it is just fixing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly66mcxo/1/

```
Example = (function() {
    var _name, _purpose;

    function getInfo() {
        return 'The purpose of "' + _name + '" is: ' + _purpose;
    }

    // Public stuff
    return {
        setInfo: function(name, purpose) {
            _name = name;
            _purpose = purpose;
        },
        showInfo: function() {
            alert(getInfo());
        }
    };
})(undefined);

Example.setInfo('someModule', 'Showing some stuff.');
Example.showInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check now

```
var Example = (function () {

    var _this = this;

    _this.getInfo = function () {
        return 'The purpose of "' + _this.name + '" is: ' + _this.purpose;
    }

    return {
        setInfo: function (name, purpose) {
            _this.name = name;
            _this.purpose = purpose;
        },
        showInfo: function () {
            alert(_this.getInfo());
        }
    };

})(undefined);

Example.setInfo('someModule', 'Showing some stuff.');
Example.showInfo();
```